# parsing + backbonejs

Tags: backbone.js

how to parse the response value..
i want to get the json value from the json value....but get problem in parsing....

```
var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#app-container',

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this,"render");
        console.log('ListView init.');
        this.counter = 0;
        this.collection = new FieldCollection();
        this.collection;
        this.render(this.collection);
    },

    events: {
        'click #add': 'addItem'
    },

   render: function(val) {
        console.log(val);
        console.log('Render called.');

    },
});
```

my json is as follow...

```
[
{
    "name": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
    "img": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
},
{
    "name": "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
    "img": "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
},
{
    "name": "ggggggggggggggggggg",
    "img": "gggggggggggggggggggg"
}
]
```

my question is that how to parse the response value...

how to access the json value in the view...

```
var FieldCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        model: Field
    },
    model: Field,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/backbonejs/myjsoncollection.json',
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('FieldCollection init.');
    },
    parse: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    }
});
```

this is the whole code...

```
$(function(){

var Field = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "shaleen",
        img: "not found",
    },
    initialize: function() {
       // console.log(this.attributes.name);
    }
});
 var FieldCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        model: Field
    },
    model: Field,
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/backbonejs/myjsoncollection.json',
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('FieldCollection init.');
    },
/*  parse: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    }*/
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#app-container',
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this,"render");
        console.log('ListView init.');
        this.counter = 0;
        var jsonfield = new FieldCollection();
        jsonfield.fetch();
        this.render(jsonfield);
    },
   render:function(collection){
        _.each(collection, function(model){
            console.log(model.get('name'));
        });

        _.each(function(model){
            console.log(model.get('name'));
            console.log(model.get('img'));
        },this);
    }
});

var listView = new ListView();
```

});

Comment: I am sorry, but do not exactly what you are trying to achieve and what exactly your problem is. Collections and models in collections do not contain json data and do not need to be parsed. They are already java script objects.

Comment: i want to fetch the json data from a json file....i am new to backbone so dnt know much abt model and collection...

Comment: where is to code to fetch the data from file??? it is unclear what and how you want to do it

Comment: thanks schacki.....i checked my code...i forgot to add parse function...see the post again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925670/backbone-js-getting-json-back-from-url

this is what i was looking for..

Answer (score 0):

The parse function is optional, you only need to implement it, if anything special should happen after you receive the data from the server. To isolate possible sources of errors, I would simplify your approach first by not connecting to your server. Please run the following code:

```
var Field = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var FieldCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Field,
});

var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#app-container',

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new FieldCollection();
        this.collection.add([{name:'name1',img:'img1'},{name:'name2',img:'img2'}]);
        this.render(this.collection);
    },

    render(collection){
        collection.each(function(model){
            console.log(model.get('name')+' '+model.get('img'));
    },this);
});
```

If this works, apply the following 2 changes:

1. Change the collection to include the url:

   ```
   var FieldCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       model: Field,
       url='http://localhost:8080/backbonejs/myjsoncollection.json'
   });
   ```
2. Change the initialize function of the View to do the fetch:

   ```
   initialize: function() {
       this.collection = new FieldCollection();
       this.collection.fetch();
       this.render(this.collection);
   },
   ```

Please run the simplified version first, if that works the extended version.

Comment: responseText: "[
↵    {
↵        "name": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
↵        "img": "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
↵    },
↵    {
↵        "name": "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee",
↵        "img": "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
↵    },
↵    {
↵        "name": "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg",
↵        "img": "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"
↵    }
↵]"

Comment: this is the response which i get when i remove parse function from the collection...how to fix this...

Comment: Did you manage to check my latest update with the render function yet?

Comment: You never do a fetch to your collection, so there will never be any call to the server and nothing to parse. My final proposal: a) provide your full code in the order you do run it and b) manually add your models and model content without going to the server so that we can check the client side before we add any new complexity with the server side, so you could do: collection.add([{name:'...', img: '...'}])