# backbone - no return after calling fetch success callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

newbie in backbonejs here. was wondering if anyone can help me with the same issue. i tried the solution above and still no luck. i am having the same issue as this post [Backbone.js - Getting JSON back from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925670/backbone-js-getting-json-back-from-url/32017266).

here is my code

```
  // Model for News Releases
  var NewsItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
  ¦ defaults: {
  ¦ ¦ releaseID: 'no releaseID at the moment',
  ¦ ¦ date: 'no date at the moment',
  ¦ ¦ title: 'no title at the moment'
  ¦ }
  });

  // Collection for our Model
  var NewsItems = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  ¦ model: NewsItem,
  ¦ url: url + "/thewheelsonthebus.php",                                 
  ¦ parse: function(response) {                                          
  ¦ ¦ console.log(response);                                             
  ¦ ¦ return response;                                                   
  ¦ }                                                                    
  });                                                                    

  var e = new NewsItems();                                               
  e.fetch({                                                              
  ¦ success: function(collection, response) {                            
  ¦ ¦ console.log('this should return something on console' + response); 
  ¦ }                                                                    
  });
```

Comment: Open the developer tools and check for any errors. You can also pass in the `error: function(` callback and see if your control is going in there. Also `url: url + "/thewheelsonthebus.php", ` where is the url coming from

Comment: url is coming from this, it is a php script that uses curl to fetch data from an api var url = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + '/ge'

Comment: Check for any errors then..

Comment: as for the error callback, yes i am receiving object. it looks like the same object as when i call fetch() without success callback

Comment: Check what response in the callback specifies `error: function(model, response, options) {`

Comment: also make sure that the url is correct. If the `console.log(response)` inside the `parse()` method is not returning anything, it then means that there is something wrong on the backeend. Try checking for errors inside the `fetch()` method. `error: function(e){ console.log(e); }`

Comment: yes, i just did `error: function(e){ console.log(e); }` and it seem to return an object but it looks empty..

`s {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}`

Comment: parse() is just returning undefined.. im thinking now if this has something to do with that im trying to call an xml file instead of json

Comment: take all what's returned when you access the url and check whether the oputput is valid json (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Comment: I think the output has to be in JSON format, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: ok yup, that is the issue.. i tried calling a sample api.. https://simplysocial.firebaseio.com/items.json and it works! thanks.. finally pinpont the real issue here..

Comment: my quess is that the ajax call can't figure out what's the output format. By default the `fileType` is automatically detected but perhaps in this case it's failing at figuring out the correct format. Therefore I'd try defining the `fileType` explicitly to xml/xthml/script...      
`this.fetch({
            dataType: "xml",
            async: false,
            success: function(collection, xml) { .... }`
But there is also one catch, you have to parse to output into a typical javascript object. (jQuery.parseXML() may come in handy in such case)

Comment: ha awesome! it works! :-D its returning a **Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.** but im not worried about this. i'll check up on it though..

Comment: this kind of warning should only appear while  `async: false `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87036/discussion-between-wracker-and-reina-lyn-ben).

Comment: apologies for the above statement, the async should be true. My bad.

Comment: ha no worries.. its fixed :-p @Wracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Wracker the solution to this was I was calling an XML data in return and the ajax call can't figure out the output format.. the fix to this is

By default the fileType is automatically detected but perhaps in this case it's failing at figuring out the correct format. Therefore I'd try defining the fileType explicitly to xml/xthml/script...

```
this.fetch({ 
  dataType: "xml", 
  async: true, 
  success: function(collection, xml) { .... }
});
```

But there is also one catch, you have to parse to output into a typical javascript object. (jQuery.parseXML() may come in handy in such case)